# The multi-part identifier "Customer.Name" could not be bound for a very simple script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables, `Customer` and `CustomerBreakdown`. There is a foreign key relationship between `CustomerBreakdown` and `Customer` via `CustomerBreakdown.CustomerId` pointing to the `Id` column in `Customer`.

I needed to drop and recreate `CustomerBreakdown` and repopulate it with some scripts.

After doing that, I need to re-establish the  foreign key relationship between the two tables.

To do that I perform the following steps:

1. Create 2 new tables `CustomerBackup` and `CustomerBreakdownBackup` and populate them with the values of the original tables by running the following two scripts:

   select * into CustomerBackup from Customer

   select * into CustomerBreakdownBackup from CustomerBreakdown
2. Truncate `CustomerBreakdown`.
3. Run the scripts to populate `CustomerBreakdown`.
4. Run the following script to re-establish the foreign key relationship between the two tables.

Here's my code:

```
update CustomerBreakdown 
set CustomerId =  Customer.Id
from  
    Customer,
    CustomerBreakdown,
    CustomerBackup,
    CustomerBreakdownBackup
where 
    CustomerBreakdownBackup.CustomerId = CustomerBackup.Id
and Customer.Name = CustomerBackup.Name
and CustomerBreakdown.CustomerLongName = CustomerBreakdownBackup.CustomerLongName
```

but the script generates the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "Customer.Name" could not be bound.

Why? And how do I fix it? Thanks!

The structure of the tables is:

**Customer**:

- `Id`: primary key
- `Name`: a string that has a uniqueness constraint on it

**CustomerBreakdown**:

- `Id`: Primary Key
- `CustomerId`: foreign key to Id field in Customer table
- `CustomerLongName`: a string that has a uniqueness constraint on it

Comment: What's the structure of the Customer table? I'm assuming it has a `Name` field?

Comment: @Hallainzil I just updated the question to answer your's. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use the proper way to join? and +1 @Hallainzil. What is the structure of CustomerBackup? because it seems like you might not have a `name` in there. Another thing, you are joining Customer with CustomerBackup, and CBreakdown with CBreakdownBackup, but their is no relation between Customer/CustomerBackup and CustomerBreakdown/CustomerBreakdownBackup

Comment: Either way, the particular script you've posted here cannot produce the said error. The issue is somewhere else or there's more to this script than what you've shown us.

Comment: @Jaques CustomerBackup and CustomerBreakdownBackup are created by the following scripts:     

select * into CustomerBackup from Customer

select * into CustomerBreakdownBackup from CustomerBreakdown

There are 4 tables. The purpose of the script that is causing the error is to create the foreign key data in CustomerBreakdown pointing to Customer by using the info in Customer, CustomerBackup, and CustomerBreakdownBackup. Thats why it has 3 joins, between those three tables.

Comment: @AndriyM, There is no more to the script.  I agree that the script is too simple and straight forward to cause this error. But I do get the error. Any ideas on how to look at what else might be causing this error?

Comment: The problem is solve now. it was indeed somewhere else. Thanks all for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you do like that??? 
I think this is much more simpler

1. Create backup tables for Customer and CustomerBreakdown.
2. Drop the relation between the orginal two tables.
3. Repopulate CustomerBreakDown
4. Make sure that CustomerBreakdown contains Customer Id that are available in the Master table
5. Create the relation again